# How to show/hide password in Widget?

Tags: flutter

i'm new to flutter and I want a button like interaction which will make password visible and invisible.Can I do it inside TextFormField?

```
child:TextField(
          obscureText: true,
          style: TextStyle(
              color:Colors.black87
          ),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top:14),
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.lock,
                  color:Color(0xff992a32)
              ),
              hintText: 'Şifre giriniz.',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color:Colors.black38
              )
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create bool variable `isVisible`:

```
bool isVisible = false;
```

setup `TextFormField` like this:

```
 TextFormField(
        obscureText: isVisible ,
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          contentPadding:const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
          prefixIcon:const Icon(Icons.lock, color: Color(0xff992a32)),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                isVisible = !isVisible;
              });
            },
            icon: Icon(
              !isVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```